# Strange behavior routing with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res){

  usermodel.findOne({ user: req.params.id }, function (err, user1){

    console.log(user1);

    if (req.session.user != user1.user) { 
       usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user, 
                           follow: user1.id }, function (err, user) {
           if (user != null) {
                 res.render('profile.ejs', {
                     user: user1,
                     ses: req.session.user,
                     foll: true
                 });
           } else {
                res.render('profile.ejs', { 
                     user: user1,
                     ses: req.session.user,
                     foll: false
                 });
           }
      });
    } else {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user: user1,
            ses: req.session.user
        })
    }
  });
});
```

And this is the mongoose schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: String,
  follow: [String],
  followers: [String]
});
```

This code, actually works, but only in local. I've update it to my VPS, and It doesn't work. I try to access to for example `http://www.xxxx.com/foo` I receive the `console.log()` output, but the page doesn't load, is loading during 2 minutes, and the browser returns an error.

Basically the code check if the user specified in the URL is the user in the req.session.user, if It isn't, we check if in the `_id`of the user specified in the URL is in the follow array of the `req.session.user`, and deppend of the result, we send a value in the variable `foll`. If it's true, it means that the `req.session.user` is following the user specified, if it false, it isn't.

In local it works, but I don't know why in my VPS doesn't work! Any solution for this...?

Thank's advance!

Comment: could you post your app.js (server.js) and any config snippets?

Comment: I killed all the process and reinstalled node, and now it works, very slow, but it works.